# Class type properties should not have static keyword?

Tags: swift, class, types, properties, static

1. This is an image from Apple's documentation example, Why do the first 2 properties have the 'static' keyword?? I thought static should be only used for structures and enums?
2. Secondly, why does this class have a stored type property? I thought classes could only have computed type properties???

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Effective Swift 1.2, `static` properties are now permitted in classes.
2. Classes have always been permitted to have stored properties.

Comment: But what would be the difference from using 'static' or 'class' keywords when declaring a class type property/method?

Comment: That's just how the language is designed: _The Swift Programming Language_ says: "You define type properties with the `static` keyword. For computed type properties for class types, you can use the `class` keyword instead to allow subclasses to override the superclass’s implementation." If you try to define a `class` stored property, you get an error message that suggests that the language does not "yet" support class stored properties: "`class` stored properties not yet supported in classes; did you mean '`static`'?"

Comment: yes I meant 'static', can I used the 'static' keyword for all type methods and type properties in a class?

Comment: You can, though if you want a subclass to be able to override the type method, you should use `class` rather than `static`. But there is a [performance benefit](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27) in  reducing dynamic dispatch.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Xcode 6.3 (Swift 1.2) release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-DontLinkElementID_20), under [Swift Language Enhancements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-SW6):

> `static` methods and properties are now allowed in classes (as an
>   alias for `class final`).
>
> You are now allowed to declare static stored properties in classes, which have global storage and are lazily
>   initialized on first access (like global variables).

Comment: but what would the difference be then, from using static rather then the class keyword?

Comment: As the quote above says: `static` (when used in the context of a class) is an alias for `class final`. `final` meaning the property/method can't be overridden. You may be interesting in [The Importance of Being `final`](http://blog.human-friendly.com/the-importance-of-being-final).